# VSCode does not enable links for each Go Editor tab

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Code for my Go development and I notice that for each `.go` file I open in an Editor, I don't by default can click on an imported package function.

Like, I have to open Command Pallette, then use `Go: Install/Update tools` and download `gopls` for each open editor.

How do I do it globally, like when I open vscode, how to make the links enabled automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Since v0.22.X released late Jan 2021, the Go extension uses gopls by default. See the [official announcement](https://blog.golang.org/gopls-vscode-go). And if the gopls is installed in your PATH, you wouldn't need to install that over and over for each open editor.